# Vectorizing numpy Multiple Condition Nested Loops

Tags: python, numpy

On attempting to produce Automatic Peak Detection in Noisy Periodic and Quasi-Periodic Signals, by Felix Scholkmann, Jens Boss and Martin Wolf in Python, I've hit a stumbling block in the implementation.

Upon attempting to optimise, I've noticed that the nested for loops are creating a bottleneck in processing time (taking 115394 ms on average to complete).
Is there a more efficient means of constructing the nested for loop?

N.B:
The parameter, signal, is a list of co-ordinates to which the algorithm will process which is of the form

> -48701.0
>   -20914.0
>   -1757.0
>   -49278.0
>   -106781.0
>   -88139.0
>   -13587.0
>   28071.0
>   11880.0
>   -13375.0
>   -18056.0
>   -15248.0
>   -12476.0
>   -9832.0
>   -26365.0
>   -65734.0
>   -81657.0
>   -41566.0
>   6382.0
>   872.0
>   -30666.0
>   -20261.0
>   17543.0
>   6278.0
>   ...

The list is 32768 lines long.

The function returns the indexes of the peaks detected to which is processed in another function.

```
def ampd(signal):

    s_time = range(1, len(signal)+1)

    [fitPolynomial, fitError] = np.polyfit(s_time, signal, 1)
    fitSignal = np.polyval([fitPolynomial, fitError], s_time)

    dtrSignal = signal - fitSignal

    N = len(dtrSignal)
    L = math.ceil(N/2.0)-1

    creation_start = time.time()
    np.random.seed(1969)

    LSM = np.random.uniform(0, 2, size=(L, N))
    creation_elapsedTime = time.time() - creation_start
    print('LSM created in %s ms' % int(creation_elapsedTime * 1000))

    loop_start = time.time()
    for k in range(1, L):
        for i in range(k+2, N-k+1):
            if signal[i-1]>signal[i-k-1] and signal[i-1]>signal[i+k-1]:
                    LSM[k,i] = 0

    loop_elapsedTime = time.time() - loop_start
    print('Loop completed in %s ms' % int(loop_elapsedTime * 1000))

    G = np.sum(LSM, axis=1)

    l = min(enumerate(G), key=itemgetter(1))[0]

    MLSM = LSM[0:l]

    S = np.std(MLSM, ddof=1)

    found_indices = np.where(MLSM == ((S-1) == 0))
    del LSM
    del MLSM

    return found_indices[1]
```

Comment: Is the PyDSTool module useful to you?
https://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/scipy-user/2009-September/022576.html

Comment: It will be as an alternate option if I can't find an adequate solution to the problem. Thank you!

Comment: The linked data file is locked (and external linkage is discouraged because of access and link-rot). Can you add a short sample of the data to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses only one loop

```
for k in range(1, L):
    mat=1-((signal[k+1:N-k]>signal[1:N-2*k]) & (signal[k+1:N-k]>signal[2*k+1:N]))
    LSM[k,k+2:N-k+1]*=mat
```

it's faster and seems do give the same solutions. You compare slices (as suggested by Ami Tavory), combine the comparisons with a `&`, which gives a `True/False` array; with `1-`operation, you transform it to zeros and ones, the zeros corresponding to where the conditions are met. And lastly you multiply the row by the result.

Comment: Thank you Ami and JPG for your assistance. Between the both of you, it is now running superbly. Thank you once again